# App disappears from Play Store

Tags: android, xml, indexing, google-play

I changed the name of this topic because I didn't want to make a new topic. So I have had my game "Birdie Pirdie" on the Play store for a while..today I added "Flappy Corbeaux" to its name so it was "Birdie Pirdie(Flappy Corbeaux)"..approx 1 hour after, it doesn't show up on the Play Store...even if I search the URL for the package name..so I changed it back to just Birdie Pirdie..and after a few hours..its still nowhere to be found. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure if this belongs on SO as its a question about Google Play search policy rather than programming. However the name is rather generic - the word 'codes' can be found in barcodes, cheat codes, etc. so tons of app there and only using one letter 'b' to make it unique isn't all that much (its a one letter slip away from vcode, gcode, ncode, etc.). Since you've just released it I would advise resubmitting with a unique name.